# Magento Too many tables error bulk updating products

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mysql, eav, custom-attributes

This morning while selecting and enabling some one hundred products in magento i got this `mysql too many table` error

Below is the snippet from the log file

```
a:5:{i:0;s:92:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1116 Too many tables; 
MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join";i:1;s:5786:"
#0 /var/www/html/dev.mysite.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

Gone through this mysql thread, http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,94448,94505#msg-94505 
which says the eav db model is flawed.. 

It also says, if i do increase the 61 table limit also, the eav model will eventually exceed this.

I'm afraid Is magento eav model not flawless? or is it because i'm having too many custom attributes ? (150+ custom attributes and sets )

I'm pointless how to deal with this.

Looking for some help
Thanks

Comment: Magmi is a better tool to achieve bulk update for products . found later

Answer (score 1):

You should use `walk()` method of core **Iterator** class for updating products in bulk. Refer to [Working with Large Magento Collections](http://inchoo.net/magento/working-with-large-magento-collections/).